# Каковы различия между ByteArrayInputStream и ByteArrayOutputStream?

Tags: java, потоки-данных

Вроде бы в оба можно записывать, вроде бы из обоих можно читать. В чем их различия?

Comment: Самое главное отличие - это назначение этих классов. Один предназначен для чтения байтов  - ByteArrayInputStream , а другой для записи - ByteArrayOuputStream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Начнем с того, что записать информацию в `ByteArrayInputStream` можно один раз - с помощью конструктора. В `ByteArrayOutputStream` записывать можно сколько угодно с помощью двух вариаций(перегрузка) метода `write`:

```
write(byte[] array, int start, int limit)
```

(запись limit элементов массива array, начиная с id, равному start)
и

```
write(int element)
```

(запись одного байта - element)

Также стоит заметить, что ByteArrayOutputStream имеет метод, вызывающий метод write к своему содержимому у других выходных потоков:

```
writeTo(OutputStream out)
```

`ByteArrayInputStream` такого метода не имеет. Однако, никто не мешает вызвать у других выходных потоков метод write к содержимому потока `ByteArrayInputStream`.
Немаловажно, что оба потока можно сбросить - вернуться в самое начало к первому записанному символу(или к символу, отмеченному с помощью метода `mark(int position)` в случае ByteArrayInputStream, по стандарту равен 0) с помощью метода `reset()`. В случае с ByteArrayOutputStream массивы трутся, с ByteArrayInputStream - перемещается лишь маячок для считывания, можно заново считывать массив.
Теперь перейдем к получению записанных byte'ов. В `ByteArrayInputStream` получить можно с помощью двух вариаций(перегрузка) метода `read`:

```
write(byte[] array, int start, int limit)
```

(получение limit элементов в массив array, начиная с id, равному start)
и

```
read()
```

(читает следующий байт)
Также можно пропустить n-ое количество байтов с помощью метода `skip`:

```
skip(long n)
```

У `ByteArrayOutputStream` все куда деревянней, у него чтение происходит  помощью следующих методов:

```
toByteArray()
```

(получаем массив байтов)

```
toString()
```

(переводит массив байтов сразу в строку)

То есть мы можем получить содержимое только полностью, не кусками.

Получение длины потока(сколько можно еще прочитать!) в ByteArrayInputStream производится с помощью метода `available()`, а в ByteArrayOutputStream(понятное дело, что полная длина) - с помощью метода `size()`.
Оба потока после работы **закрывать не нужно**.

Вот такие, вот, различия. А какой из них использовать - решайте, опираясь на данные мной выше св-ва каждого из классов.